# Using linq with string split

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split, model

workareaRefs is a string of random values splitted by comma i.e. 4,7,1,7 etc.
I am setting properties to TrackDataFilter and would like to set the Workareas 
which is of type IList with the values in workareaRefs var.

So Workareas should contain the values in workareaRefs stored in the variable named r.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

```
var workareasRefs = workareaRefs.Split(',');

var r = new TrackDataFilter
{
    DatePreset = preset,
    Workareas = new List<TrackFilterGenericRef>
    {
        new TrackFilterGenericRef
        {          
            Ref = 2, Type = Enums.ContentTypes.Workarea
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure If I understand your question correctly, so by guessing a bit, I would assume you want to do the following

> WorkAreas = new List(workareasRefs);